# Removal of highly identical columns in a matrix in R

Tags: r

Coming from

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10)     
row.names(data) <- c(1:10)
colnames(data) <- letters[1:10]
corr <- cor(data, method="spearman")
corr.a <- corr[rownames(corr)=="a", ,drop=FALSE]
```

I have created an object that consists of the row "a" of the the correlation matrix "corr" of the pairwise column rank correlation of matrix "data". I want to identify all values > 0.4 in "corr.a", but here i fail to keep the column names, for example:

```
corr.a.sig <-  corr.a[corr.a>0.4,drop=FALSE]
```

corr.a.sig is now a simple vector with no additional information. What i want to achieve is to:

- identify all values > 0.4 in row a, and create a matrix/dataframe to 
  keep colname information
- create a vector with all column names with values > 0.4
- look up the names in that vector in the col names of the initial matrix "data" and remove the respective columns from that matrix.

In other words, i want to identify very similar columns in a count matrix and remove them from said matrix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can column-index the 1x10 `corr.a` matrix with `drop=T` (which is the default) to get a vector that preserves names. You can then use that vector to do the required removal of columns of `data`:

```
set.seed(4);
data <- matrix(rnorm(100),10,10);
row.names(data) <- 1:10;
colnames(data) <- letters[1:10];
corr <- cor(data,method='spearman');
corr.a <- corr[rownames(corr)=='a',,drop=F];
corr.a.sig <- corr.a[,corr.a>0.4];
corr.a.sig;
##         a         f
## 1.0000000 0.4787879
data[,!colnames(data)%in%names(corr.a.sig)];
##              b          c          d           e          g           h          i           j
## 1   0.56660450  1.5408150  0.1534642  1.34370863 -1.0685231  0.15867690  1.2869283 -1.27765990
## 2   0.01571945  0.1651690  1.0519326  0.18153538  1.0644507 -0.48566507 -0.2141497 -0.79801248
## 3   0.38305734  1.3076224 -0.7542112  1.29251234 -1.3127218 -0.95890607 -0.5747455  0.15908242
## 4  -0.04513712  1.2882569 -1.4821891 -1.68804858  2.0636947  0.18051729 -1.4707270  0.61479763
## 5   0.03435191  0.5928969  0.8611319 -0.82099358  0.1313830  0.72173428 -1.0327384  0.68794796
## 6   0.16902677 -0.2829437 -0.4045198 -0.86214614 -0.2316884 -0.36954048 -1.3065249 -0.04705101
## 7   1.16502684  1.2558840 -0.2274054  0.09884369 -0.3973555  0.23753831 -0.8382524  2.33032168
## 8  -0.04420400  0.9098392  0.9340962 -0.37565514  0.8894321 -0.66592211 -1.1306537 -0.57756599
## 9  -0.10036844 -0.9280281 -0.4658959  0.72390416  0.5261690 -0.79680751  0.3687482  0.96847913
## 10 -0.28344457  1.2401808 -0.6375435 -1.79738202 -0.1712732 -0.05169693 -0.2018030 -0.27753563
```